# \parbox "textwidth" for the combined width of a subset of table cells

Tags: tables, boxes, width

I would like the parbox width of the text in a multicolumn to be calculated automatically from the combined width of the cells that the multicolumn spans. (Their width will vary in different copies of the table.) Is there a way of doing this?

**The details are as follows**: One row of my five-column table contains a multicolumn, spanning four of the columns. I want the text in that multicolumn to wrap correctly, but I don't want to specify an actual numerical width. Instead, I want the width to be determined by the actual combined width of columns 2-5 in the previous row. I've written the basic code for the table (simplified for this illustration) this way, using a tentative numerical width of "2in":

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|} \cline{2-5}
{\bf A} & first & second & third & fourth, of variable length \\ \cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\parbox{2in}{fifth, also of highly variable length but
   long enough to need to wrap.}} \\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}
```

I have used a parbox because the contents of the multicolumn contains images and text that I want to be able to treat as a unit, but I've left those details out here in order to keep the picture simple. The result looks as I want it to, except that the content of the multicolumn has too much space to the left and right, because I used an ill-chosen manual setting for the width.

**The point**: How can I avoid setting the parbox width manually and instead have it calculated based on the width of the other columns?

[This question was earlier posted on stackoverflow but I was urged to ask it again on this site. Thanks for your patience.]

---

(**EDIT**) Martin Scharrer's code, below produces an interesting problem for me: \colwidth seems to become only as big as the first measured column. I find that this only happens when I use certain packages that I need for Chinese in XeLaTeX:

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
```

The output becomes:

[image: columns not working]

Comment: Could you delete your question on stackoverflow then, otherwise it will most likely be migrated here, causing the exact question to exist twice.

Comment: Please note that `{\bf ...}` should not be used in LaTeX2e, but `\textbf{...}` (or `{\bfseries ...}` if you really need a macro with doesn't take an argument). Also instead of `\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\parbox{2in}{` you can use `\multicolumn{4}{|p{2in}|}` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You measure the width of the columns by catching them into a box using the `lrbox` environment and then measuring and accumulating their width (and the column separation between).

Using special column types defined with the help of the `array` package makes this actually very easy to handle in the tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newlength{\mycolwidth}
% First column (re-)sets to width.
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\global\mycolwidth=-\tabcolsep\addmycolwidth}c<{\endaddmycolwidth}}
% All other to be measured cells have type `C` which uses `c` internally:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\addmycolwidth}c<{\endaddmycolwidth}}
% The `P` type then uses the saved width:
\newcolumntype{P}{p{\mycolwidth}}

\newsavebox{\mycolwidthbox}% box to save cells in
\newenvironment{addmycolwidth}{%
   \begin{lrbox}{\mycolwidthbox}%% catch cell content into a box
}{%
   \end{lrbox}%
   \usebox{\mycolwidthbox}%% place cell content back
   % Add width and column sep: (globally because this code is still executed inside the cell which acts like a group)
   \global\advance\mycolwidth by \wd\mycolwidthbox
   \global\advance\mycolwidth by \tabcolsep
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|F|C|C|C|} \cline{2-5}
\textbf{A} & first & second & third & fourth, of variable length \\ \cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{4}{P|}{fifth, also of highly variable length but
   long enough to need to wrap.} \\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{c|F|C|C|C|} \cline{2-5}
\textbf{B} & first & second & third & fourth, of much much longer length \\ \cline{2-5}
&  \multicolumn{4}{P|}{fifth, also of highly variable length but
   long enough to need to wrap.} \\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Resulting tables]

Comment: Thank you very much. As it happens, my results were not as expected once I included the packages I need for Chinese with XeLaTeX; I've added a .png file to my original post with an edit.

Comment: @brannerchinese: I fixed it now. The issue is that the original version used `\global\addtolength` which doesn't work properly with the `calc` package which is loaded by some of the packages you use. I changed the code to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\TBox \newlength\TWidth
\def\Tab#1{%
\sbox\TBox{\tabular{@{}c|c|c|c@{}}#1\endtabular}
  \usebox\TBox
  \global\TWidth=\wd\TBox\global\advance\TWidth by -\tabcolsep}  
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|} \cline{2-2}
\bf A & \Tab{first & second & third & fourth, of variable length}\\ \cline{2-2}
      & \parbox{\TWidth}{fifth, also of highly variable length but
                        long enough to need to wrap.}\\ \cline{2-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am still experimenting with the results.