# Tabular and itemize

Tags: tables, lists, itemize

I'm having a big problem...I am trying to make a nice table which in the left side has just text and in the right part it may contain some itemized elements. This is how i'm doing it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
...
\begin{tabular}{r| p{5cm}}
  {\bf Text} &
  Data \\ \hline
  {\bf Itemization} &
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{item1}
    \item{item2}
  \end{tabular}
  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

But like this the `\hline` will be 5cm long. Is there a way of making it as long as the top bar (the one who comes from `\documentclass{report}`)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Which `\hline` is too short?

Comment: As reference, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: I think the answer(s) in [Know the cell width with `tabular*` or include a paragraph box without specifying its width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108565/5764) would help. The suggestion, use the [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package, which provides the `tabularx` environment: `\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX} ... \end{tabularx}`

Comment: @jjdb: Eheh, i almost forgot, I'm new here =) hi everybody :P regarding you question...all of them. I guess they are all "bound" to the p{5cm}...i would like to make it as long as possible (without going out of the margins ofcourse).

Werner: thanks! I'm kinda new to Tex-World, and any suggestion is welcome =)

Answer (score 4):

Please always provide complete documents showing packages used (the report class doesn't use a ruled headline by default for example). Also `\bf` shouldn't be used unless you are aiming fro LaTeX2.09 compatibility.

You just need to make the table full width using `tabular*` for example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}

\hrule

\bigskip

xx x x x x

\bigskip


\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r| p{5cm}@{}}
  \textbf{Text} &
  Data \\ \hline
  \textbf{Itemization} &
  \mbox{}\par\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topsep-\partopsep\relax}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item item1
    \item item2
    \end{itemize}
    \par\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topsep-\partopsep\relax}
    \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here you are the packages used:
`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}`
`\usepackage[english]{babel}`
`\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`
`\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`
`\usepackage{graphicx}`
`\usepackage{wrapfig}`
`\usepackage{float}`
`\usepackage[small]{caption}`
`\usepackage{color}`
`\usepackage{fancyhdr}`
`\pagestyle{fancy}`
`\lhead{}`
`\chead{}`
`\rhead{}`
`\lfoot{}`
`\cfoot{\thepage}`
`\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{+1,3cm}`
`\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1,3cm}`
`\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`
`\begin{document}`
And here's the result of your code:[link](http://imgur.com/tedxRS3)