# Would like to have a table like this: Any help please

Tags: tables

[image]

Have been able to do this using table environment (tabularx) but without success. Need this for my dissertation. Thanks

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: And what is your question? Centred headers? p-columns? Flushed left text? Itemizations in tables? All of this can be found in many posts on this site here. The only hint you give is `tabularx` but this is not needed here. (if it is, explain why!). If you have typed something already, why don't you post that in order to make it easier for volunteers? That is your 14th question so this should be clear already. I did not vote down as you can still edit and improve, but I summarize the most certain motivation of the downvoter.

Answer (score 6):

Taking some advice from [Tabular and itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108912/5764) there is a little vertical adjustment required for `itemize` at the start of a cell. The same goes for the end of the `tabular`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ *{4}{L} }
  \toprule
  \centering Author(s) &
  \centering Aims &
  \centering Modelling approach &
  \centering\arraybackslash Conclusions \\
  \midrule
  You and me and them &
  Obtain general insights into the population-dynamical properties of possible scenarios of 
    scrapie transmission in a sheep flock &
  \mbox{}\par\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topsep-\partopsep\relax}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108912/5764
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Deterministic model framework comprising most of the aspects that are of relevance
      (potentially or in reality) to the transmission dynamics of scrapie
    \item General insights from analytical considerations and approximations
  \end{itemize} &
  \mbox{}\par\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topsep-\partopsep\relax}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108912/5764
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Dependence of basic reproduction number~($R_0$) and generation time on other
      parameters gives insight into the effects of these parameters
    \item Simplified models yields insights into interplay of horizontal and vertical
      transmission, and the characteristics of endemic scrapie
  \end{itemize} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]

  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Other than that, this is a typical [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) implementation. Specialized `L`-columns are made for ease-of-use, matching a `\raggedright` `X`-column.

Comment: +1 for being that busy. If you do `\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}` it improves quite a lot...

Comment: diligent I mean... not busy. Puh, to early for English...